# Javascript function with parameter doesn't work in MVC

Tags: javascript, function, onmouseover

below you can see my code in View;

I just want to change the color of the div with onmouseover event. I get the categories data from northwind database with Viewbag. I can get category names on screen but when I mouseover, div color does not change. Is there something wrong with "i" parameter or code? Thanks for your help.

```
<script>

function colorchange(i) 
{
    var a = document.getElementById(i);
    a.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';
}


</script>

<div id="div1">
<label>Category Name&nbsp;;&nbsp;</label><br />

@for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.CategoryCount; i++)
{
    <div id="@i" onmouseover="colorchange(@i)"
    style="vertical-align:middle;height: 30px; width: 100px;border-style:ridge">
        <span>@ViewBag.Categories[@i].CategoryName.ToString()</span><br />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: What's going on with the @s?

Comment: These `@` symbols look like ASP.NET MVC Razor syntax.  Is that the case?  If so, show the client-side code that gets generated.

Comment: why not use the CSS [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) pseudo class

Comment: This code is very low quality. First of all, you miss the '' around the id @i. Second you haven't declared @i as a variable, and therefore you can't use it as a parameter in colorchange. And btw. it's backgroundColor and not backGroundColor.

Comment: @fzzle I write this code in MVC. There is Category Data in Viewbag.Categories. I get this data with for loop and it works.  I can see category names on the screen. I have made changes putting " around div id making it div id="@id" and changed backgroundColor spelling but it doesnt work again.

Comment: @livefreeor Your code is full of bugs; I was aware that the ones I pointed out weren't the only. And btw. you hadn't written anything about MVC in you question.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem in jquery with following code. thanks for your helps

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("div").hover(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
    },
    function () {
        if ((this).onclick)
        {
            $(this).css("background-color", "lightblue");
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).css("background-color", "white");
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div").click(function () {
        $("div").fadeTo("quick",0.15);
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.99);
        $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
        });
    });
```